# Plots points for a box chart on a kendo line chart

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I'm trying to draw a square on a kendo line chart with the jQuery syntax. I thought I should be able to pass it an array of x,y points and have them join up by setting the chart up as line chart, but that doesn't work. The scatter chart takes an array of x,y point and allows me to plot the points of the corners of the squares, but if I change the chart type with the same data to "line" the points are now plotted at different y values on the same x value (i.e. in a vertical line which is completely wrong).

Is it possible to plot a box chart with a kendo chart?

(I am using C# MVC4, not that that makes a difference)

Answer (score 0):

The line series are categorical, i.e. the points are always plotted in-order. As you've noted, the scatterLine variety is an XY-chart and allows plotting arbitrary shapes.

Combining XY and categorical charts is not supported. If this is what you're trying to achieve, then try converting the line series to scatterLine by adding an implicit X value.

Please, feel free to make suggestions for built-in features at [the Kendo UI UserVoice portal](http://feedback.kendoui.com/)